# button only works occasionally using AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Below there's the function I use in my JavaScript file. It works sometimes when I clicked the button, but sometimes it doesn't.
How can I fix this issue?

```
function getEditForm(id) {
    console.log("masuk editform")
    $.ajax({
        url: `${baseUrl}/todos/${id}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            access_token: localStorage.getItem("access_token")
        }
    })
    .done(todos => {
        editPage()
        $("#edit-title").val(`${todos.title}`)
        $("#edit-description").val(`${todos.description}`)
        $("#edit-due-date").val(`${(todos.due_date)}`)
        $("#edit-todo-button").on("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            editTodo(id)
        })
    })
    .fail((xhr, text) => {
        swal("Oops!", xhr.responseJSON.error[0], "error")
        console.log(xhr.responseJSON.error[0])
    })
}
```

Below the code inside document ready, it should be jus like that, right?

```js
$("#btn-edit").on("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  getEditForm(id)
})
```

below the html code, using append method to make m app dynamic:

```
$("#card-content").append(`
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="todo-${el.id}">
                    <div class="card mt-3 mx-1 shadow" style="width:auto">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${el.title}</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${el.description}</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Due date: ${el.due_date}</p>
                        <span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block d-inline mt-2" id="btn-status-${el.id}" style="width:auto;"  onclick="updateStatus(${el.id})"><i class="bi bi-x-square"></i>  Not Done</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block d-inline" id="btn-edit-${el.id}" style="width:auto;"><i class="bi bi-pencil" onclick="getEditForm(${el.id})"></i>  Update</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block d-inline" id="btn-delete-${el.id}" style="width:auto;"><i class="bi bi-trash" onclick="deleteTodo(${el.id})"></i>  Delete</button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `)
```

Comment: In what way does this fail?  What specifically happens?

Comment: Any errors in console? What means *"Occasionally"*?

Comment: @David it doesn't fail as in showing any errors. it's just sometimes when i click the update button, it works ("masuk editform" shows up in the console), sometimes not

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it doesnt give any errors in the console. so when i click the button, sometimes it works, sometimes not (nothing happens, i think it somehow renders the response late)

Comment: @OlfiaR: Well, for starters, the code shown has no matching element for `$("#btn-edit")`  And if you're clicking on a element which does match that selector and it doesn't invoke the click handler you're using then that would mean the click handler isn't attached to that element.  Which could mean that the element didn't exist when you tried to bind the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

See here you have an onclick function inside your fontawesome icon(i) tag so the getEditForm() function will be called only when you click on icon not on button part,

also the id you have given in button tag is dynamic

```
id="btn-edit-${el.id}"
```

so I think the below code will not work

```
$("#btn-edit").on("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  getEditForm(id)
})
```

Workaround is just include onclick event on button tag instead of icon tag and pass id as a parameter to it

Comment: thank you! it did work perfectly by moving the onclick function into the button block.